# Abstract Algebra: Rings and Integers with modulos

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question? Is $Z$$_1$$_8$ a ring? Field?

This is only my second theoretical math class so I'm struggling heavily. I know for it to be a ring it needs to be 1). closed under addition/multiiplication, 2).assosciative laws must hold for add.multi, 3). distributivce laws must hold for add/multi, 4). commutative laws must hold for add./multi 5). additive identity, 6). additive inverse

My professor hasn't done many examples so I'm stuck on how to show the proof for each step.

1).Would this work? Let $\overline{a}$$\overline{b}$$\in$ $Z$$_1$$_8$,  $\overline{a+ b}$$\in$ $Z$$_1$$_8$ b.c $m+n$ $\in$ $Z$ and same with multiplication?

With 2), 3), 4), wouldn't they all hold true because the set of all integers holds true?

Comment: What’s your definition of $ℤ_{18}$?

Comment: Proof that it’s not a field: 9 x 2 = 0, so 9 and 2 are non zero 0 divisors. Now prove that 0 divisors cannot be units, then you have it’s not a field!

Comment: The set of all integers modulo 18.

Comment: A typesetting tip, enclosing something in curly braces `{}` forms a group (in latex and mathjax). So to have $18$ show up as a subscript (or superscript, or under a radical, etc), use `Z_{18}`.

Comment: Or for not a field you can brute force compute all products products of either 2,3 or 9 and show that none of them have a multiplicative inverse

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a commutative ring with unit. You can check every axiom by hand.

In general you can show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime. This follows directly from the following property:

> $\overline{a}\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

To prove the above property it is useful to remember Bézout's theorem.